# Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int' - greatest common divisor

Tags: swift, xcode, return, func

This is my code:

```py
    import UIKit
    
    func gcd(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> (Int) {
        if a == b {
            return a
        } else if a > b {
            gcd(a - b, b)
        } else {
            gcd(a, b - a)
        }
    }
    gcd(9, 6)
```

The algorithm works like this:

| 9 | 6 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 |

It gives me a correct answer when I do `print(a)` but It does not give me the result when I do `return`.

Comment: You better read error messages carefully sometimes it's very descriptive and can guide you to the answer

Comment: single liner `b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b)` or using the same logic in your post `a == b ? a : a > b ? gcd(a - b, b) : gcd(a, b - a)`

Answer (score 0):

You miss `return` in the last 2 cases

```
func gcd(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    if a == b {
       return a
    } else if a > b {
       return gcd(a - b, b)
    } else {
       return gcd(a, b - a)
    }
}
```

To call

```
print(gcd(9, 6))
```